# How to switch IOS network interfaces when connected to wifi without internet connection (IoT device)

Tags: ios, react-native, iot

So,
I'm working on a RN app that connects to IoT device. which is Wifi hotspot with no internet connection.

Using [react-native-wifi-reborn](https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn) library for managing the connection.

Which uses `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` behind the scenes (on IOS)

Which works ok..

My issue is that while app is connected to the wifi hotspot I need to have internet connection to  call my server api and show some info from a webpage.

On Android network selection is accessible and its possible to force network usage
Could not achieve this with IOS..

Also saw that [Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_external-accessory_wireless-configuration) is a thing but could not figure out how can be implemented for the mentioned above needs

Can't rally find a lot of information about IoT with IOS but surly I'm not the first confront this in 2020 with IOS

Help